# Fortigate SD-WAN Performance SLA and static route updates, can the network still ping the WAN gateways when the route is down?

Tags: fortigate, fortinet, sd-wan

I'm using a Fortigate in order to load balance and have redundent internet acces for a remote site. Going there is painful as it involves taking a boat and go to a remote but inhabited island.

The SD-WAN is configured with two members. WAN1 is an ASDL gateway using regular copper landlines. WAN2 is a 4G receiver wich can communicate with cellular networks. Both have a web user interface that enables the user to configure them using the gateway IP address. For example https://192.168.8.1 to configure the 4G receiver.

[image: SD WAN members configuration]

There are three Performance SLA rules in place. The first one tries to ping a google DNS server in order to check that we can reach the internet. It marks as "Down" the WAN interface that does not permits to ping the google server.

[image: SLA Perfornace Checks]

The first rules tries to reach a DNS server and updates the static routes accordingly
[image]

The second and third rules are trying to reach the gateways on what is still our local network. These rules are basically measuring the Ethenet connection between the WANx interfaces of the FortiGate and the Ethernet port of the gateways.

[image]

When the internet connection is lost, then the WAN status is updated and traffic is router smoothly on the other interface.

However I would like to see more information on the web interfaces of the gateways. For example on the 4G gateway, there is a webpage that tell me the LTE signal strength among other informations. But if internet is down (because the ping cannot reach 8.8.8.8) and the Fortinet has disabled that route, how could I reach the configuration webpage at https://192.168.8.1/ ? I've tried and got a "destination not reachable" message on the browser.

If I'm not mistaken the SLA checks are performed continuoulsy, so the WAN2 interface is still up and running. It responds to ping and tries to send pings as well. If I do not check the "Update Static Route" box, then traffic may not be rerouted correctly when we loose internet on one of the gateways. But when I check it, I cannot access thegateway webpage to see what is going on with the signal. I'm kind of stuck in a deadlock here and would like some advice about how to configure it to have internet redundency and still the ability to access the webpage ?

Best regards